# Get list items ids using rest api and integrated to like functionality (id value is not static)

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ajax, like

Thanks for this article [Enable like function from catalog page via javascript object model - improve this?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134497/enable-like-function-from-catalog-page-via-javascript-object-model-improve-thi/239644#239644)  is very useful and its working on my page, but i need your help, i am calling rest api function to read the first 3 items of the list and i am trying to integrate the like functions code in my main code and to do that i have insert this: `< div id='idnumb' >"+itemid+"< / div >` in the ajax code to read id's value of each item and i am trying to set the id value to the variable as `var sItem = $("div#idnumb").text();` but i have a main problem that i need to set the `sItem` value after the load of the list contents ( title, id , description content) ??? i tried many workaround steps but still cannot read the id of each item.

First question, this is a good solution to convert the like function code to read dynamic item value, by using  `$("div#idnumb").text()`

and if not, please suggestion another solutions

Comment: The div has id "idnumb" but not using $('div#idnumb') in jQuery?

Comment: Yes sorry i have used $('div#idnumb').text()  i will update the question

Comment: The issue is when add any variable for example var  itemid = 1; in the $(document).ready ... the like function is not reading this variable to define item id for the like..... please check this article https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134497/enable-like-function-from-catalog-page-via-javascript-object-model-improve-thi/239644#239644 and let me know how i can add the variable sItem declaration on load of the page

Comment: Is it a timing issue the code should run after page fully loaded?

Comment: Yes its a timing issue i have used   $(document).ready(function () {  setTimeout(function(){ var parItem = $('div#idnumb').text() },100);  }); but how i can reinitialize the code of the like script function and set parItem = sItem in that code [ https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134497/enable-like-function-from-catalog-page-via-javascript-object-model-improve-thi/239644#239644 ]  please help me

Comment: I avoid use document.ready because it never work for me. I usually use $(window).bind("load", function() {} )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I use window.bind instead of document.ready to run script after the page loads.

Sample code as below:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
 // Your codes here     
});
```

Comment: This is the updated code:
$(window).bind("load", function() {
     setTimeout(function(){  // Your codes here 
  }, 200); 
});